# emulating mobile browsers on Os X

Tags: android-emulator, mobile-safari

what's the best way to emulate iPhone's Mobile Safari and Android's browser on Oxs X ? I've tried some stuff, but it's not reliable and doesn't match 100% the renderning on the mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

For android you can download SDK, and run the browser from the emulator.  This will get you exactly the browser that will run on the device.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For mobile safari, you need the iOS SDK:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action

Which has the iPhone and iPad emulators built in.

Not sure about android on OSX